# swttoolkits: what are the diffrences between swt 3.5 to swt 3.6?

Tags: swt

Does anybody know what are the main differences among these two SWT toolkits versions ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a "New and Noteworthy" link on the Eclipse SWT website that might answer your question: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/R3_6/new_and_noteworthy.html

Comment: thanks for the link, but i couldn't find there a differences between those two version...